# When is the Layout of an activity loaded in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my activity(snippet):

```
setContentView(R.layout.main)
//Some Time consuming code
```

As you can see the time consuming code is placed after the `setcontentview`. This activity takes a lot of time to load. to confirm I removed the time consuming code and the activity is displayed very quickly.My question is I am doing the time consuming work only after `setContentView` the layout, then why does it take so much time to display at least the layout .

Comment: You need to understand Android activity cycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app is running on a single thread UI thread. It cannot show the view until it has finished running everything else.

You need to use an `AsyncTask` or a thread for any time consuming code. Have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 2):

Every time consuming tasks should be done in a non-UI Thread. Consider using an AsyncTask.
To answer your question, the activity will only be displayed when the whole onCreate method is finished. So it sets its content view, then it executes the reste of the onCreate method (your time consuming code) then it shows.

For your information, here is the documentation for AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

You should do all your time consuming work in the onResume() method. then it may take less time to complete the onCreate() method and your layout will be loaded faster.